# Sum the values in a column of a 2d array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-sum

I have seen various posted about this question so am aware some answers to this may exist. however I am none the wiser after reading these.

I have an array that is like the following.

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 95659865986
        [invoiceNumber] => 6374324
        [invoiceTitle] => Monthly
        [invoiceStatus] => Paid
        [accountId] => 6235218753
        [totalExVat] => 158.95
        [dateCreated] => 1 Apr 2012
        [vatAmount] => 20.00
    )
```

All I wish to do is do array sum on the `vatAmount` values of this array.

As the following doesnt seem to be doing much.

```
(array_sum($account_invoices['vatAmount'])
```

Comment: You have only one "vatAmount" element of the array, it is inappropriate to sum it.

Comment: assuming $account_invoices is your multidimensional array, $account_invoices['vatAmount'] is not defined, whereas $account_invoices[0]['vatAmount'] is.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Just a way to do it:

```
$sum = 0;

foreach($account_invoices as $num => $values) {
    $sum += $values[ 'vatAmount' ];
}
```

Comment: Additional comment to this solution: I assume that you have an array containing n arrays which have the index 'vatAmount' present.

Answer (score 76):

If you have PHP 5.5+ you can do this without looping or using a callback (since function calls are relatively expensive) ... just use:

```
$sum = array_sum(array_column($account_invoices, 'vatAmount'));
```

Answer (score 26):

I would use array_map to reduce the array to only what is needed. Bear in mind, this will only work with PHP 5.3 onwards.

```
$total_vat = array_sum( array_map(
                 function($element){
                     return $element['vatAmount'];
                 }, 
             $account_invoices));
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use `array_map` first to collect the `vatAmout` value.

```
$sum = array_sum(array_map(function($var) {
  return $var['vatAmout'];
}, $account_invoices));
```

Answer (score 4):

A way to do this using a PHP 5.3+ anonymous function

```
$account_invoices = array(
    0 => array(
        'id' => '95659865986',
        'invoiceNumber' => '6374324',
        'invoiceTitle' => 'Monthly',
        'invoiceStatus' => 'Paid',
        'accountId' => '6235218753',
        'totalExVat' => 158.95,
        'dateCreated' => '1 Apr 2012',
        'vatAmount' => 20.00
    ),
    1 => array(
        'id' => '95659865987',
        'invoiceNumber' => '6374325',
        'invoiceTitle' => 'Monthly',
        'invoiceStatus' => 'Paid',
        'accountId' => '6235218753',
        'totalExVat' => 208.95,
        'dateCreated' => '1 May 2012',
        'vatAmount' => 25.00
    ),
);


$sumDetail = 'vatAmount';
$totalVAT = array_reduce($account_invoices,
           function($runningTotal, $record) use($sumDetail) {
               $runningTotal += $record[$sumDetail];
               return $runningTotal;
           },
           0
);
echo $totalVAT;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using [`array_map()`](http://php.net/array_map) and select the `vatAmount` column first:

```
$totalVatAmount = array_sum(array_map(function($account_invoices) { 
    return $account_invoices['vatAmount']; 
}, $account_invoices));
```

Of course, internally this performs a double loop; it's just that you don't see it inside the code. If you use [`array_reduce()`](http://php.net/array_reduce) then you can get rid of one loop:

```
$totalVatAmount = array_reduce($account_invoices,
     function($totalAmount, $item) {
         $totalAmount += $item['vatAmount'];
            return $totalAmount;
     },
   0
);
```

**However, if speed is the only interest, you should use `foreach`. Because there is no function calls used to calculate the final sum. This solution is faster than other solution.**

```
$totalVatAmount = 0;
foreach ($account_invoices as $item) {
    $totalVatAmount += $item['vatAmount'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this directly with `array_sum`, which would sum everything in the array.

You can do it with a loop:

```
$sum = 0;
foreach($items as $item)
    $sum += $item['vatAmount'];
```

or you can filter the array (in this case **it isn't very convenient**, but if you had to calculate, say, S&H expenses plus VAT plus..., from each single item, and then sum...):

```
// Input: an array (element #n of array of arrays), output: VAT field
function getVAT($item)
{
    return $item['vatAmount'];
}

// Array with all VATs
$vats = array_map('getVAT', $items);

$sum = array_sum($vats);
```

Answer (score 1):

Also you can do this (if you like array_sum function):

```
foreach($account_invoices as $num => $values) {
    $vatAmount[] = $values[ 'vatAmount' ];
}

$Total = array_sum($vatAmount);
```

Answer (score 1):

Just another way to do this using array_reduce:

```
$vatMount = array_reduce($account_invoices, function($total, $value) {
    return $total + $value['vatAmount'];
});
```

Answer (score 1):

array_sum_multidimensional Helper function

```
if (!function_exists('array_sum_multidimensional')) {
    /**
     * returns the sum of a element from an array of arrays
     */

    function array_sum_multidimensional(array $array, $elementKey){

        $sum = 0;

        foreach($array as $key => $value) {
            $sum += $value[ $elementKey ];
        }

        return $sum;
    }
}
```