# How to update a total sum from a row based on id in php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following columns in my database using MySQL.

```
 id|product_1|product_2|product_3|Total
 1    25         25        25       75
```

However, let's say that I want to update one specific row in a form i.e. product_2 by 1.

```
id|product_1|product_2|product_3|Total
1    25         26        25       76
```

How do I accomplish the above using either Raw or Eloquent MySQL?

I've tried so many things like changing my code, searching on Google, YouTube, but I couldn't find a solution.

So the code below is what loads my table with populated data from MySQL.

```
public function index()
{
    $ProductsPost = ProductsPost::all();

    $sum_total = ProductsPost::select(DB::raw('product_1 + product_2 + product_3 as total_products'))->where('id', 1)->total_products;
    return view('products/index')->with(
        [
            'products_post' => $ProductsPost,
            'sum_total' => $sum_total
        ]
    );
}
```

Below is my update function.

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{

    $ProductsPost = ProductsPost::find($id);

    $ProductsPost->update($request->all());

    ProductsPost::where('id', $id)->sum('product_1', 'product_2', 'product_3');

    if ($ProductsPost->wasChanged()) {
        // changes have been made
        return redirect('products')->with(['success' => 'Changes were successfully saved.']);
    } else {
        return redirect('products/'.$id.'/edit')->with(['error' => 'No changes made.']);
    }
}
```

Am I supposed to add an update here to the total column?

Again, the result I'm looking for is the total sum of columns in a row based on id. For example, if product_2 changes to a different value, I want that reflected for the Total column. The Total column should sum the collection of values from the three columns product_1, product_2, product_3.

Comment: Ideally, you wouldn't have a `Total` column, that'd be calculated manually as and when needed. However, in your scenario, yes, you'll need to update the total too. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12838729/multidimensional-array-array-sum

Comment: Any time you find yourself with enumerated columns (above, say, 2), alarm bells should start ringing. Consider whether your schema design is optimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a **generated column**, you can use the `storedAs($expression)` modifier in your migration as following:

```
Schema::create('products_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->double('product_1');
  $table->double('product_2');
  $table->double('product_3');
  $table->double('total')->storedAs('product_1 + product_2 + product_3');
});
```

## or

You may use the `virtualAS($expression)` modifier, which its value will be calculated on the fly, but based on your scenario you want to store the value and be update on the insert or update.

See the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/migrations#columns) and this [Question](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/migration-column-modifiers#) too.

## Note

product_1, product_2, product_3 as columns, looks like you need to do some normalization.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a '*On Update*' constraint on your product_1, product_2 & product_3 column. On every update on this column, total will become sum of three product columns.